# Correcting SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

Tags: python, python-2.7

New to python as of a few days ago. Trying to write a simple calculator program but when I run it, I get a `SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing` error when I input a '+' for choosing my operator.  I am stuck on why this is happening and think it may be due to my spaces vs tabs? Can anyone help me?

```
num1 = int(input('pick number 1: '))
num2 = int(input('pick number 2: '))

choose = str(input('Pick an operator: '))

if (choose == '+'):
    print add(num1, num2)
elif (choose == '-'):
    print sub(num1, num2)
elif (choose == '*'):    
    print mult(num1, num2)
else:
    print div(num1, num2)

def div(num1, num2):
    return num1 / num2    

def add(num1, num2):
    return num1 + num2

def mult(num1, num2):
    return num1 * num2

def sub(num1, num2):
    return num1 - num2
```

Comment: `input()` in Python 2 tries to run the input as a Python expression. `+` is not a valid, complete expression. Use `raw_input()` instead.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thank you.  Would this script have run in Python 3?

Comment: No, you can simply use `raw_input()` everywhere you use `input()`.